# combine 3 different mysql queries in to one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have 3 different table .. and i will be given a string as input and i have to find out the emil from last table.

here input is 'html'

```
mysql> select id from track where name LIKE 'html';
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 116  |  
+------+
```

based on the id provided by above query ....

```
mysql> select name from resource where task='2' AND track ='116';
+------+
| name |
+------+
| 1005 |  
+------+
```

based on the name provided by above query..

```
mysql> select email from users where id = '1005';
+--------+
| email  |
+--------+
| pinhu | 
+--------+
```

i want to combine these query in to one, so can some one please help me in building the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know MySql very well but this query should work:

```
select t.id, r.name, u.email
from track t
inner join resource r on r.task = 2 and r.track = t.id
inner join users u on u.id = r.name
where t.name LIKE 'html';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select u.email
from users u
inner join resource r on u.id = r.name
inner join track t on r.track = t.id
where t.name  = 'html'
and r.task='2'
```